# ui-draggable not working properly inside modal-dialog on Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I have a cascade of modals that needs to be draggable, so I implemented it with Bootstrap Modal and jQuery UI draggable.

However, the code I used works on Internet Explorer and Firefox just fine, but in Chrome, the inner modal gets a glitchy offset when you try to drag it.

Further debugging made me connect the bug with the fact that `modal-dialog` uses `position: fixed`, and jQuery UI draggable uses positive values for `top/left`, thus changing the position of the inner modal incorrectly.

But still, the values for top/left generated by jQuery UI draggable are the same for all browsers, but just Chrome positions it wrong.

the code:

```js
$('#Cad_Expen').draggable(
  { 
    handle: '#Expen > .mod-header', 
    containment: 'window'
  });

$('#Cad_Point').draggable(
  {
    handle: '#Point > .mod-header',
    containment: 'window' 
  });
```

```css
#Cad_Expen { 
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  left: calc(50% - 400px);
  top: calc(50% - 250px);
}
#Cad_Point {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  left: calc(50% - 300px);
  top: calc(50% - 150px);
}
.modal-dialog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.modal {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

/* irrelevant CSS */
.mod-header {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
}
.mod-expen-body, .mod-point-body {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
}
.mod-expen-body {
  height: 500px;
}
.mod-point-body {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="Cad_Expen" class="modal fade in" style="display: block;">
  <div id="Expen" class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="mod-header"></div>
    <div class="mod-expen-body"></div>
    <div id="Cad_Point" class="modal fade in" style="display: block;">
      <div id="Point" class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="mod-header"></div>
        <div class="mod-point-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can also find it on CodePen:
http://codepen.io/carvalho23lucas/full/jBJbLy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was the `transform` of the bootstrap `.modal.in .modal-dialog` that was causing the glitch.

To solve the problem, simply put this in your site's css file:

```
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
  -moz-transform: none !important;
  -ms-transform: none !important;
  -o-transform: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
}
```